# Where is the kubelet on AWS EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, metrics, kubelet, amazon-eks

Our AWK EKS cluster does not seem to have 'kubelet' pods or any pod containing the label `k8s-app=kubelet`.
Therefore, monitoring the cluster, we're missing some metrics like `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` which, as far as I can track, should have been provided by cAdvisor via a `kubelet` pod.

Our AWK EKS only has `aws-node-xxxxx`, `coredns-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx` and `kube-proxy-xxxx` pods in the `kube-system` namespace.

I looked up the metrics of the `aws-node`, but this does not contain the `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` metric.

Any idea why there is no `kubelet` pod on EKS? I thought it is quite basic, so it should be there somehow. Is it hidden? Can it be accessed for metrics?
How to get metrics like `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` on EKS?

Answer (score 0):

Kubelet is run as a systemd daemon inside EKS worker nodes. You can SSH into the EC2 worker instance and try running 'systemctl status kubelet' to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question refers to the [Kube Prometheus Stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) and you refer to the `k9s-app=kubelet` label that the ServiceMonitor targets. When you use the Prometheus operator it will by default create a service in the kube-system namespace that has the label. The service points to the node IPs which expose the kubelet metrics on port 10250.
If the ServiceMonitor and Service resources exist and you see the failing jobs in the Prometheus target list then it most likely fails because of missing or incorrectly configured network policies or security groups.

Note that in the default EKS setup there are neither any restricting network policies nor security groups that would block access to the metric port, i.e. it should work out of the box.